# Shrinkwrap modifier not applying correctly

Tags: modifiers

[image]When I apply the Shrinkwrap modifier, the mesh isn't above the surface of the other like it should be. Plus, when the modifier is on the bottom, it deforms correctly, but then when applied, it is all messed up. How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything unexpected with the current version or with 2.73.  Maybe you have non-uniform scaling in Object mode; try (Ctrl+A) Apply->Rotation and Scale.  If that doesn't work then you may have to isolate the portion of the scene that is causing problems and upload it to PasteAll.org and paste the URL here.  Without a .blend file, there is a lot guessing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**About the modifier stack:**

When a modifier is applied, it has to be applied as if it is at the top of the modifier stack (the first one), as to achieve the previewed result you will need to apply all other visible modifiers as well.

**About the Shrinkwrap issue in particular:**

A couple of things could be causing this. You could try:

1. Make sure your target mesh is high enough resolution (enough faces to deform vertices to)
2. Use the *Offset* slider
3. Use the *Keep Above Surface* option

*Screenshot:*
[image: Modifier Screenshot]

Comment: How do you use the offset slider?

Comment: Click+Drag or you can click and type a value. It basically tells how much to add to the shrinkwrap location, same idea as a margin.

Comment: Okay I did everything on the list, but it still isn't working... Any suggestions?

Comment: @veryRandomMe im having issue with shrinkwrap i have posted the question but did not get answer hope i get from your side thanks http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74414/why-shrinkwrap-not-working-on-the-mesh