# Why shrinkwrap not working on the mesh

Tags: mesh

I have a mesh and a plane that i want to shrinkwrap on that mesh. When shrinkwrap added its not wrap in the shape model. To the side its cut shape and not fully covered. On the top some part it got shrink and some not. Any help or suggestion plz Thanks
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: unrelated, if using "project "on surface" be sure to select an axis (none are selected by default)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you shrink-wrapping to a single object? You're only allowed a single target object in the shrink-wrap modifier. You can duplicate and merge your objects for the shrink-wrap process; that way, your original model state stays intact.

Also, if you are using other modifiers, play with the order of your modifiers by using the up and down arrow buttons in the modifier panel. I believe modifiers occur from the top down.

Lastly, the shrink-wrap modifier can only work with the geometry its given. subdividing your sheets will add more geometry and give you a more accurate wrap.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:
After downloading your file and applying the methods I described above in a few clicks, I achieved the result you were searching for. There was not enough geometry in the 'sheets'. Also take note of the offset value in the shrink-wrap modifier. see image below:
[image: didueventry]

Comment: I have attach my file in the question section can you go through it and clear. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for replying with the image. The plane is not covered the below mesh its look cut from the side. I have attach my the file with red mark i need it to be covered completely.

Comment: @lemon can i get the answer for the question. Thanks

Comment: Please TRY before asking additional questions. Think about your scenario. you're using the shrink-wrap modifier. It behaves like shrink-wrap. if you want the sheets all around the object, Then turn the sheets into tubes so that they shrink-wrap from all sides. done.